# C language struct accessing elements

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Ournode {
  char x, y, z;
};

int main() {
  struct Ournode p = {'1', '0', 'a' + 2};
  struct Ournode *q = &p;
  printf("%c, %c", *((char *)q + 1), *((char *)q + 2));
  return 0;
}
```

I came across this question on geeksforgeeks(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-language-2-gq/input-and-output-gq/)  (question 21). How is *q accessing the elements of p? what if we had struct like

```
struct Ournode {
  int a,b,c;
  char x, y, z;
  int d;
};
int main() {
  struct Ournode p = {3,4,5,'1', '0', 'a' + 2,6};
  struct Ournode *q = &p;
  printf("%c, %c", *((char *)q + 1), *((char *)q + 2));
  printf("%d, %d\n", *((int *)q + 1), *((int *)q +2 ));
  return 0;
}
```

In this case how can we access the elements?I get garbage output sometimes depending upon the order in which i create Ournode (i.e. a,b,c first then x,y,z or x,y,z first then a,b,c).

what is happening behind the scenes here? how is q accessing the elements?

Comment: Fyi, you could change the type of `q` to `void *` and have the same output, and likely questions. All those casts are important, relevant to the output you're seeing, and basically disregarding the pointer-type of `q` and thus making it irrelevant. You should learn more about what casting does (then avoid using them, as they generally mean you're doing something questionable, especially for beginners).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is `*q` accessing the elements of `p`?

It does so through a `char` pointer, using a rule that the address of the `struct` must match the address of its initial element (i.e. field `p.x`). However, the standard allows the compiler to insert padding after `x`, so adding `1` to `((char*)q)` may not necessarily yield the address of `y`.

You can fix your program as follows:

```
printf(
    "%c, %c"
,   *((char *)q + offsetof(struct Ournode, y))
,   *((char *)q + offsetof(struct Ournode, z))
);
```

Since `((char*)q)` points to part of `int` field `a`, printing `%c` from these addresses yields implementation-defined re-interpretations of parts of `int`'s representation as `char`. As far as printing `int`s is concerned, you should add the same `offsetof` trick to counter the results of potential padding.

**Note:** I am yet to see a compiler that inserts padding between `char`s, but I didn't find anything in the standard preventing it from doing so. The situation would be different if instead of `char x, y, z` you used `char x[3]`, because padding between array members is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> how is q accessing the elements?

This has been already answered, so I want to answer this other question of yours.

> In this case how can we access the elements? I get garbage output sometimes depending upon the order in which i create Ournode (i.e. a,b,c first then x,y,z or x,y,z first then a,b,c).

If you want to access the members of `struct Ournode` through a pointer `q` to that node, there is an operator `->` that makes this possible.
Your code will now look like this.

```
int main() {
  struct Ournode p = {3,4,5,'1', '0', 'a' + 2,6};
  struct Ournode *q = &p;
  printf("%d, %d, %d, %c, %c, %c, %d", , q->a, q->b, q->c, q->x, q->y, q->z, q->d );
  return 0;
}
```